# Windows phone 8 localization

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

In my windows phone application there are some buttons. I want to change the text according to the devices selected culture Info. I have added the required resource file also made the required changes but still the changes are not reflecting on the UI. Any help will be useful.

Is there any thing that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to including the resource files in the project you also need to explicitly specify which cultures you're supporting.
You do this in the project properties. On the "Application" tab there is a list of supported cultures. You must check the box next to the ones you wish to support.

[image]